# How to get view model directly in layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout, model

I'm working on a practice where I minify most of my javascript in static files, and then each view has something like this:

```
@section Script
{
    @Html.Action("MinifyJavaScript", "Resource", new { viewPath = "~/Views/User/Register.Js.cshtml", model = Model })
}
```

Which in turn renders the tiny, non-static, pieces of javascript code, like the one below:

```
@model UserRegisterModel
<script>
    (function ($, b) {
        $(function () {
            b.views.user.register('@Url.Action("ValidateInput", "User")');
        });
    })(jQuery, bruttijjimo);
</script>
```

This allows me to cache javascript in views more heavily, since only the parts that vary with the model can change (and are generally treated as partial views)

Now I'd like to further upgrade this practice by removing the need of a layout section, and by convention, render the javascript partial view (which is passed the same model as the view) right after the view. I already created the method to compress the javascript in the view. And there's also the convention that javascript for a view must be in a `.js.cshtml` file, and share the model with the view.

What I'd need is to grab the model for the view from the layout, and the name of the view, too, and render it there.

This would only work or be needed for the actual view, since partials use a script manager if they need to emit javascript.

So: how can I grab the model for the view from the layout? The rest I can figure out, but this one is eluding me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So: how can I grab the model for the view from the layout?

`@Model` should give you what you are looking for.

This being said I didn't quite understand what you are doing but the fact that you have javascript inside your view instead of having it in a separate javascript file and leaving the caching stuff to the browser and reinventing some wheels kind of feels wrong.

Comment: that's the point, all the javascript I have in my views was a single call to a separate script file, and now I want to remove that coupling and have a convention much like "Controllers should end in `Controller`" where I don't need to reference that script line at all in the HTML view itself.

Comment: I hadn't even tried `@Model` assuming it was the model for the layout, thanks.